# Key check in object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have wrote a script to check any missing fields from the objects and then return Ids of Item that has missing fields.

It is returning:

```
[ '222', '333' ]
```

Which I expected to return:

```
['333']
```

Why is it returning `222` id as well?

```js
function returnMissingData(items) {
    const missing = items.reduce(function(acc, item) {
        const fields = [
            'Cost',
            'Name'
        ];

        for(const key of fields) {
            if (!item[key] || item[key] === undefined) { 
                acc.push(item.Id);
                break;
            }
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);

    return missing;
}


console.log(returnMissingData([
    {
        Id: "111",
        Name: "Name 1",
        Cost: 100,
    },
    {
        Id: "222",
        Name: "Name 2",
        Cost: 0,
    },
    {
        Id: "333",
        Name: "Name 3",
    }
]));
```

Edit: It must have properties and it can not be false as Boolean.

Comment: Should `item[key] === undefined` not be `typeof item[key] === 'undefined'`?

Comment: Because zero (as Number) is falsey while '0' (as String) would be truthy so `Cost: 0` gets pushed to your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Solution:

Change:

```
if (!item[key] || item[key] === undefined)
```

To:

```
if (item[key] === false || item[key] === undefined)
```

---

### Why is this happening?

As you're iterating through your keys you check for `!item[key]` - which equates to a check for `falsy` values. Falsy values, as implied by the name Fals-*y*, do not necessarily mean `false`. It is the same as saying:

```
item[key] == false
```

the above uses type coercion to verify if `item[key]` and `false` values are analogous. It will change a `number` through coercion and then check if it's `falsy`. In this case `0` is `falsy`.

By using:

```
item[key] === false
```

We remove type coercion from the code. It's more sane, and does exactly what you'd expect instead of guessing.

---

### Working Code:

```js
function returnMissingData(items) {
    const missing = items.reduce(function(acc, item) {
        const fields = [
            'Cost',
            'Name'
        ];

        for(const key of fields) {
            if (item[key] === false || item[key] === undefined) { 
                acc.push(item.Id);
                break;
            }
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);

    return missing;
}


console.log(returnMissingData([
    {
        Id: "111",
        Name: "Name 1",
        Cost: 100,
    },
    {
        Id: "222",
        Name: "Name 2",
        Cost: 0,
    },
    {
        Id: "333",
        Name: "Name 3",
    }
]));
```

Comment: It's not clear in the OP that they want to find properties that are `false` it says they are looking for missing values.

Comment: @MarkMeyer That's a good point. :) I'll look over the question - I may have assumed because of the code that they were excluding `false` as well as `undefined`

Comment: It must have properties and it can not be false as Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach using  filter/map.

Filter uses `Array#some()` to find any missing keys

```js
function returnMissingData(items) {
      const fields = ['Cost','Name'];
      return items.filter(o => fields.some(k => !(k in o))).map(({Id}) => Id);      
}


console.log(returnMissingData([
    {
        Id: "111",
        Name: "Name 1",
        Cost: 100,
    },
    {
        Id: "222",
        Name: "Name 2",
        Cost: 0,
    },
    {
        Id: "333",
        Name: "Name 3",
    }
]));
```

Comment: What does `Set()` do?

Comment: I like the `filter` approach better. But why make a set? Why not just check if `key in object`? Or even if `obj[key] === undefined`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer yeah...that's simpler

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back The [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) wasn't really needed but has simple api and is quicker lookup than looking through arrays

Answer (score 1):

Because `!item[key]` will be valid for falsy values like 0. As the object with ID 222 has a key with 0 it will match.

Instead, you should check if the object has the key provided with 
`myObj.hasOwnProperty('key')`

```js
function returnMissingData(items) {
    const missing = items.reduce(function(acc, item) {
        const fields = [
            'Cost',
            'Name'
        ];

        for(const key of fields) {
            if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key) || item[key] === undefined) { 
                acc.push(item.Id);
                break;
            }
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);

    return missing;
}


console.log(returnMissingData([
    {
        Id: "111",
        Name: "Name 1",
        Cost: 100,
    },
    {
        Id: "222",
        Name: "Name 2",
        Cost: 0,
    },
    {
        Id: "333",
        Name: "Name 3",
    }
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hasOwnProperty()`

```js
function returnMissingData(items) {
    const missing = items.reduce(function(acc, item) {
        const fields = [
            'Cost',
            'Name'
        ];

        for(const key of fields) {
            if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
                acc.push(item.Id);
                break;
            }
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);

    return missing;
}


console.log(returnMissingData([
    {
        Id: "111",
        Name: "Name 1",
        Cost: 100,
    },
    {
        Id: "222",
        Name: "Name 2",
        Cost: 0,
    },
    {
        Id: "333",
        Name: "Name 3",
    }
]));
```